# Rails 3 :group => :field sorted by created_at desc

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I select all records grouped by a column sorted by created_at desc.

I might want to retrieve all the latest comments for each Articles. No matter what I do the group(:article_id), will always return the oldest comment.

Best regards.
Asbjørn Morell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't find an easy answer with SQL - group happens before sort (since group is generally for aggregate data). Just keep a `latest_comment_id` field on your Article record, and then join comments on latest_comment_id when you find your articles.

If you want multiple comments per article, you're going to have to resort to either using multiple queries, or maintaining a temp table with just the latest comments per article.

Answer (score 16):

Something like :

```
Comment.order('created_at DESC').all
```

That should do it :)

If you just want the first result, use `first` instead of `all`.
You also can use `limit`. Exemple to get the firsts 5 results :

```
Comment.order('created_at DESC').limit(5).all
```

Comment: But how do you avoid select multiple records for each article? I need a single comment for each article - sorted by created at.

Comment: Well I'm not sure that you can do with Rails helpers only. This is looking quite complicated ! I have done some research on Google and I found that : http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/. Is this what you are trying to do ? Whatever, please post your solution if you find one ;)

Comment: That's exactly what I am trying to do. Will go for the solution with a latest_comment_id column in my Articles model.

Answer (score 1):

```
Comment.group(:article_id).order('created_at DESC')
```

Comment: Won't work. The query will select all comments grouped by article_id, but the ordering will happen after the group part - you will get the oldest comment.