# How do I get the latest records depending on the foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-postgresql, pg

I am using rails with postgres.
I have a table called 'attempts' which belongs to a 'users' table.
I want to retrieve all attempts but only show the latest attempt for each user.

So I want code something like this:

```
Attempt.group(:user_id).having('latest(created_at)')
```

The above code does not work.

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255286/rails-3-group-field-sorted-by-created-at-desc

Comment: Ok, I dont need to use group, but i just want some query that returns the attempt if it is the lastest attempt for that student. For a set of attempts

Comment: Maybe something like: `Attempt.where(:user_id => user_id).order("created_at DESC").first`

Comment: not tested this though so give it a try - I'm sure someone else will pitch in if I'm wrong

Comment: I dont think you are interpreting the question correctly. I want an activerecord array of attempts as the result where each attempt must have a unique user and that attempt is the last attempt for that user.

Comment: ahhh did you get your answer 6 years later?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Rails but it could be that "latest" doesn't exists in Postgresql. Could try with ...having('max(created_at)')

Otherwise this should do the job:

```
sql = "Select user_id, max(created_at) from attempt group by user_id"
records_array = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

[Inspiration source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14824453/rails-raw-sql-example)